# Add file to installation and windows support for sbt-native-packager 0.8

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to build an installer (.msi) for my Play 2.3 Java application.
For one how don't know Play, it's use for create RESTFull server.

So I want to use sbt-native-packager (v0.8 because of compatibilities problem with Play 2.3). I have successfully created a .msi file and it works. Bu I have to handly edit the generated .bat file for adding some java parameters and add some files to the bin directory (server key and certificates). I think I have found out how to add java parameters to the bat file programaticaly.

My questions are :

1. How to add files to the installation dir (key and certificates files)
2. Is the Java Server Application archetype supported by this version of sbt-native-packager for windows ? Because it apear I have to handly make a script to run my server in background task (with a durty VB script)... I have read in the documentation that sbt-native-packager should allow to use Windows Service Manager but it's not documented so far...

Here is my build.sbt file :

```
import NativePackagerKeys._

name := """IdTabDriver"""
version := "1.0.0.1"

name in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageSummary in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageDescription in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

maintainer in Windows := "Access France"

organization := "Access France"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.10",
  "org.rxtx" % "rxtxcomm" % "2.0-7pre1"
)
```

I'm pretty new to this system so if I have done some thing wrong please tell me.

Comment: See [Windows Docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/windows.html), [Configure Java App for Windows](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html?highlight=bash#configuring-for-windows) and [Universal Packaging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#customize) for examples. Sadly there is no server functionality for windows yet.